# What is the relationship between sheaf cohomology from different global sections functors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be a ringed space, and $F$ be a sheaf of abelian groups on $X$. Then $H^i(X, F)$ is the right derived functors of the global sections functor. However, there are at least three different global sections functors that we can take derived functors of:

1. Forget the ringed space structure and just consider $X$ as a topological space and $F$ is a sheaf of abelian groups. Then, the global sections functor is $Ab(X) \rightarrow Ab$.
2. If $F$ has an $O_X$-module structure, then we have another global sections functor $O_X-mod \rightarrow O_X(X)-mod$. That is: the category of sheaves $O_X$-modules to the category of $O_X(X)$-modules
3. We can also restrict (2) to the case where $F$ is quasicoherent. That is: we have a functor $QCoh(X) \rightarrow O_X(X)-mod$.

My question is: what is the relationship between them? Injective objects in the category of quasicoherent sheaves is not the same as injective objects in the category of sheaves of $O_X$-modules, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14737/can-injective-modules-over-r-give-non-injective-sheaves-over-spec-r) for an example.

Hartshorne's proposition III.2.6 states that the derived functors $O_X-mod$ to $Ab$ coincide with the cohomology functor. Does this mean that (2) and (1) result in the same cohomology groups, after applying the forgetful functor?

If $X$ is an affine scheme, then the global sections functor is exact. This would imply that the $H^i(X, F)$ for $i \geq 1$ is 0 for the third global sections functor. What about the first and second global sections functors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your analysis of the equivalence of (1) and (2) is correct. (2) and (3) are equivalent in the case that $X$ is noetherian, and it is the same idea, though covered slightly later in Hartshorne: III.3.6 says that every quasicoherent sheaf on a noetherian scheme can be embedded in a quasicoherent flasque sheaf, and flasque sheaves are acyclic for global sections, so one may compute cohomology using them. In the general case for $X$ not noetherian, the proof above does not apply and there ought to be counterexamples (see for instance [this answer of Roland](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2563845), though it does not contain an explicit counterexample).

The final paragraph contains a slight misconception: $X$ being an affine scheme only means that the global sections functor is exact on quasicoherent sheaves. We will show that we can have non-quasicoherent sheaves with higher cohomology on affine schemes via a dirty trick. Over an infinite field $k$, the underlying topological spaces of the schemes $\Bbb A^1_k$ and $\Bbb P^1_k$ are homeomorphic (both have one generic point and $|k|$ closed points, and are equipped with topologies where the closed sets are exactly the finite sets of closed points). Let $u:\Bbb A^1_k\to\Bbb P^1_k$ be such a homeomorphism. Then $H^i(\Bbb A^1_k,u^{-1}(\mathcal{F}))=H^i(\Bbb P^1_k,\mathcal{F})$ for $\mathcal{F}$ a sheaf of abelian groups, and so by picking $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{O}(-2)$, for instance, we can find a sheaf of abelian groups with higher cohomology. The moral here is that we can't tell if a scheme is affine or not just from it's underlying topological space.

(2) should also be false but I'm unsure about a specific counterexample. I think you can use the example of the above paragraph by putting a funny $\mathcal{O}_X$-structure on the sheaf in question, but I'm having a brain-freeze about it right now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's is an alternative way of proving that the sheaf cohomology computed for sheaves of abelian groups is the same as the one for sheaves of modules (i.e., the equivalence of 1 with 2).

> **Lemma.** Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\xrightarrow{f}(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)\xrightarrow{g}(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)$ be morphisms of ringed spaces. Then $R(g\circ f)\cong Rg\circ Rf$.

*Proof.* One applies [015M](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/015M). Indeed, if $\mathcal{I}$ is an injective $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, then $\mathcal{I}$ is flasque ([09SX](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09SX)), so $f_*\mathcal{I}$ is flasque too; thus, $f_*\mathcal{I}$ is acyclic ([09SY](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09SY)). $\square$

Let $f:(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\to(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ be a morphism of ringed spaces. We have a commutative diagram of ringed spaces
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
(X,\mathcal{O}_X)@>{f}>>(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)\\
@V{\varphi}VV@VV{\psi}V\\
(X,\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_X)@>>{g}>(Y,\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_X)
\end{CD}
$$
where $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_A$ is the $\mathbb{Z}$-constant sheaf over a topological space $A$. (In the following, keep present that a sheaf of abelian groups is the same as a $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$-module, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1098613/394668).) Using that $\varphi_*,\psi_*$ are exact, by the previous lemma we have $Rg_*\circ\varphi_*=Rg_*\circ R\varphi_*\cong R(g_*\circ\varphi_*)=R(\psi_*\circ f_*)\cong R\psi_*\circ Rf_*=\psi_*\circ Rf_*$. Contemplated carefully, the isomorphism $Rg_*\circ\varphi_*\cong\psi_*\circ Rf_*$ means that the derived pushforward of modules coincides with the derived pushforward of abelian groups. If particular, if we set $Y=\{*\}$, $\mathcal{O}_Y=f_*\mathcal{O}_X$, by [01E4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01E4) we get that the sheaf cohomology for modules is the same as the one for abelian groups.